# Room Persistence inside of Lib

Tags: android, android-room

I am looking for a good way to import Room Persistence inside of my Lib to export .aar . I have the following issue that .aar cannot handle dependencies.

When I export my arr and import into another project as lib, it seems as it has no scope to room.

my lib Gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
archivesBaseName = '*****'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.1.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // Write out the current schema of Room
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

configurations {
    deployerJars
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-beta3'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-beta3'
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Publish the AAR as an artifact in an artifact repository. It is the artifact metadata (e.g., POM file for a Maven-style repository) that has transitive dependency information.

Comment: hello its a private use .aar its not public i cant user public repository

Comment: Artifact repositories do not have to be public.